# How to execute obj file on Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, adb

I have C code which I want to execute on Android's libraries.

I compiled this code by the `NDK` in Windows, like that:

```
set SYSROOT=%NDK%\platforms\android-17\arch-arm
cd %NDK%/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe --sysroot=%SYSROOT% -c "C:\main.c" -o "C:\main.o"
```

then I pushed the .obj file by the `adb`:

```
adb push C:\main.o /data/local/tmp
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/main.o
```

after that I tried to execute this file:

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/main.o
```

but I got the following error:

```
[Android] not executable: magic=7F45
```

so I tried to execute via Android application by the following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String fileName="/data/local/tmp/main.o";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        //get file type
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")+1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        //run
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
        startActivity(intent);
   }
```

but when I try to run my application, it closed and I got the message:

```
unfortunately, myApplication has stopped
```

Can anyone help me?

**Edit:**

I think that the compilation is not match to my Android machine. How can I find which `gcc` I need to compile for specific Android version? In the NDK(`%NDK%\toolchains`) there are some compilers, and I don't know how to decide which one I need to use with.

Comment: This is not a proper way to build for Android.  You should follow the NDK documentation and use an Android.mk with ndk-build to either build an executable or, more in keeping with the intent of the NDK, a jni shared library to be called from a Java application.  You can also follow the instructions to create a stand-alone toolchain and use with an existing project build system, but that gets tricky.

Answer (score 0):

It simply isn't possible to execute a simple object file, because it misses important information to run properly (this is in no way limited to Android, just the way C/C++ compilation works).

You should instead generate a straight executable, e.g.:

1) Generate a standalone toolchain for your system
  2) Use /path/to/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -o main main.c
  3) adb push main /data/local/tmp/
  4) adb shell /data/local/tmp/main

If you don't want to generate a standalone toolchain, you'll need to take care of adding the proper command-line arguments when invoking the NDK binaries directly. Frankly, I think you'll be better off writing a tiny jni/Android.mk and calling ndk-build instead.